# Phonegap: Save login page username,password and time in local text file

Tags: cordova

I have an android app which is made using phonegap. It has a login page and I need to save the username and password entered locally in a text file. Any solution to this will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different options depending upon your preferences.

1) File API. Documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html)

2) You can use local Storage. Documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) and [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)
Within local storage you have various options.
  a) Local Storage
  b) WebSQL
  b) SQLite Database
  c) Indexed DB